# Urgent problem: Keyboard of a mac running ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, mac

I'm freaking out/panicking massively. My Mac (2008) with Ubuntu 14 has decided not to work anymore: keyboard and mouse aren't operative at all -I'm stuck with the login. The keyboard is working (I was able to reset the Pram and even select which hdd on boot by pressing Alt). Can't even enter Grub (Shift isn't cooperating as the rest of the keyboard). Fn+F6 same. No response from both keyboard and/or mouse. Usb keyboard not working as well.

Oh, forgot to mention I do have an assignment by midnight and if I can't get into it I basically screw up my first at uni. Can't access any other computer but could call a friend if any usb cd etc is needed.

Answer (score 1):

- Turn off your PC and unplug it.
- Remove the keyboard from the (USB?) plug. Wait 30 seconds. Plug the keyboard back in.
- Reboot PC.

Does that work?

Was there a thunderstorm with a powersurge that fried your keyboard? You do have a surge protector on your PC components right?

Can you try another keyboard of the same model on Ubuntu? What were the results?

Comment: Okay, the keyboard is working (as stated previously) if I have to select options on the mac "Bios". It seems not to work if ubuntu kicks in.

Comment: Obviously everything is protected.